# Google drive spreadsheet exceeded maximum excution time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

My script in my spreadsheet on Gdrive for insert link id of file in folders like this:

```
function listFolders(folder) {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     sheet.appendRow(["Name", "FileId"]); //writes the headers
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXX")

     var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

     while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
         var name = subfolders.next();

         var files = name.getFiles();

         var cnt = 0;
         var file;

         while (files.hasNext()) {
             var file = files.next();
             cnt++;

             data = [
                 file.getName(),
                 file.getId()
             ];
             sheet.appendRow(data);
         };
         
     }

 }
```

How to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list from the subfolders just under the specific folder using Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.
- As the additional goal, you want to add "FolderName" to the column.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) In your situation, I thought that when the number of files is large, the process cost will become high. In this answer, this is modified.
- It seems that `folder` of argument is not used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function listFolders() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXX")
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  var values = [["Name", "FileId", "FolderName"]]; // Modified
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var name = subfolders.next();
    var folderName = name.getName(); // Added
    var files = name.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      data = [file.getName(), file.getId(), folderName]; // Modified
      values.push(data);
    }
  }
  var cnt = values.length;
  console.log(cnt);  // You can see the total number of files at the log.
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modification, the file list is put to an array and the array including the file list is put to the Spreadsheet using `setValues`.

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the file list from all subfolders under the subfolders in the specific folder, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function listFolders() {
      const getAllFolders = (id, list = [["Name", "FileId", "FolderName"]]) => { // Modified
        const fols = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFolders();
        let temp = [];
        while (fols.hasNext()) {
          const fol = fols.next();
          const folderName = fol.getName(); // Added
          temp.push(fol.getId());
          const files = fol.getFiles();
          while (files.hasNext()) {
            const file = files.next();
            list.push([file.getName(), file.getId(), folderName]); // Modified
          }
        }
        temp.forEach(id => getAllFolders(id, list));
        return list;
      }

      const id = "###"; // Please set the top folder ID.
      const values = getAllFolders(id);
      var cnt = values.length;
      console.log(cnt);  // You can see the total number of files at the log.

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  ```
- When above modification was not the direct solution of your issue, I would like to propose to use Drive API. In this case, I think that this Google Apps Script library can be also used. https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

About your following replying,

> I want to know which folder on my drive this file belonged to. `const getAllFolders = (folderName,id, list = [["FolderName","Name", "FileId"]]`

Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about the output values of your additional question, the following script is what you want?

#### Sample script:

```
function sample() {
  const getAllFolders = (id, list = [["FolderName", "Name", "FileId"]]) => {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    const folderName = folder.getName();
    const fols = folder.getFolders();
    let temp = [];
    while (fols.hasNext()) {
      const fol = fols.next();
      temp.push(fol.getId());
      const files = fol.getFiles();
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const file = files.next();
        list.push([folderName, file.getName(), file.getId()]);
      }
    }
    temp.forEach(id => getAllFolders(id, list));
    return list;
  }

  const id = "###"; // Please set the top folder ID.
  const values = getAllFolders(id);
  var cnt = values.length;
  console.log(cnt);  // You can see the total number of files at the log.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,last question: how to add FolderName column in spreadsheet by this method?

Comment: @Mahdi Yousef Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `how to add FolderName column in spreadsheet by this method?`, I modified above both scripts. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: I want to know which folder on my drive this file belonged to.
` const getAllFolders = (folderName,id, list = [["FolderName","Name", "FileId"]] `

Comment: @Mahdi Yousef Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. About your additional question of `I want to know which folder on my drive this file belonged to. const getAllFolders = (folderName,id, list = [["FolderName","Name", "FileId"]]`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. But I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? From this, I would like to try to understand it. For example, can you provide the sample output value you expect?

Comment: @Mahdi Yousef For example, when you want to use the sample script in my "Note" section, and you want to use `const getAllFolders = (id, list = [["FolderName", "Name", "FileId"]]) =>` instead of `const getAllFolders = (id, list = [["Name", "FileId", "FolderName"]]) =>`, how about modifying from `list.push([file.getName(), file.getId(), folderName]);` to `list.push([folderName, file.getName(), file.getId()]);`? If this was not the result of your additional question, can you provide the sample output value you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about your additional question.

Comment: @Mahdi Yousef Now, by guessing the output of your additional question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about your additional question. Although I could understand about your 1st question and could resolve your issue, I deeply apologize that I cannot understand about your additional question soon. This is due to my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you so much,this is great.

Comment: @Mahdi Yousef Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

This minor modification runs okay for me:

```
function listFolders() {
     var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     sh.appendRow(["Name", "FileId","Count"]); 
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder id")
     var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
     while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
         var fldr = subfolders.next();
         var files = fldr.getFiles();
         var cnt = 0;
         while (files.hasNext()) {
             var file = files.next();
             sh.appendRow([file.getName(),file.getId(),++cnt]);
         };
     }
 }
```

This was my output:

| Name | FileId | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Slide22.png | Redacted | 1 |
| Slide21.png | Redacted | 2 |
| Slide20.png | Redacted | 3 |
| Slide19.png | Redacted | 4 |
| Slide18.png | Redacted | 5 |
| Slide17.png | Redacted | 6 |
| Slide16.png | Redacted | 7 |
| Slide15.png | Redacted | 8 |
| Slide14.png | Redacted | 9 |
| Slide13.png | Redacted | 10 |